# Windows 7 taskbar properties

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

This is currently the style of my windows 7 taskbar. But I don't want it to be like that.

[image]

I want to change it, and make it like this. I have searched many times but I couldn't find the right answer because I don't know the right keywords for that.

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly.. Win7 taskbar are semi-transparent, so the colour hue depends on what is the background wallpaper is, or what is actually currently showing on maximised (or if you drag a window below the taskbar). If you simply change the wallpaper background to the correct colour, it should be like that. - I think.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the taskbar → Properties → Taskbar Tab. There should be a little section that says "Preview Desktop with Aero Peek," under that, check the checkbox that reads "Use Aero Peek to preview the desktop."

Open run, and run `services.msc`. Find "Desktop Window Manager Session Manager" or "Desktop Windows Manager". Right click, go to properties, be sure it is set to automatic or delayed start and not manual or disabled. Start the service. If that still doesn't work try this command in run or command prompt (you may have to run as Administrator):

```
rundll32.exe Dwmapi.dll,DwmEnableComposition
```

By default Aero Peek is enabled as soon as you update it from installation; because, for me it auto enabled as soon as it updated, where it used to show the same thing you show in the upper image.

You may require Service Pack 1 for Windows 7, but I don't think so. If not be sure you have all the updates for Windows 7, including all the optional ones that says "Update for Windows 7 for ... Systems (KB......)", under Windows Update.